# How can I put two or more arrays into a single array?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to take the values of the three arrays put them together into one array and output it but I have no idea how to do this. I would appreciate any answers to lead me in the right direction.

```
    // num is user entered as number of times to output
    int[] skuNum = new int[num];
    int[] letters = new int[4];
    int[] l_p_Num = new int[4];

    int count = 1;
    // Fill numbers array
    for (int s: skuNum) {
        System.out.print(String.format("%05d", (s + count)) + "     ");
        count++;
        // Fill letters array
        for(int i: letters) {
            i = (rnd.nextInt(26) + 'A');
            System.out.print((char)i);
        }
        System.out.print(" ");
        for(int q: l_p_Num) {
            q = rnd.nextInt(9) + 0;
            System.out.print(q);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: How are you going to order the values in the  new array? Just put all of one array's values in then the next array, then the 3rd?

Comment: What I want is to have a new array with the three arrays values in an index. What I have will give me 00001     DVAH 4238. 00001 is in the first array, DVAH in the second, and 4238 in the third. What I now want is 00001     DVAH 4238 in a single array.

Comment: What does that mean??

Comment: Have a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
int[][] arrays = {skuNum, letters, l_p_Num};
```

or

```
int[][] arrays = new int[][] {skuNum, letters, l_p_Num};
```

to create array of arrays and iterate through each array with for loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrays .length; i++) {
   // each array from arrays
   for (int j = 0; j < arrays [i].length; j++) {
       //each int value from each array
       System.out.println(arrays[i][j]);
   } 
}
```

To display the result in your "00001 DVAH 4238" format

```
for (int i=0; i<skuNum.length; i++) {
   String row = String.valueOf(skuNum[i]) + String.valueOf(letters[i]) + String.valueOf(l_p_Num[i]);
   System.out.println(row);
}
```

Comment: This worked for me but I'm still a beginner so I don't know what exactly I have to do to get rid of this:  [I@6bdf28bb [I@6b71769e [I@2752f6e2

Comment: I added an example to display result in your custom format

Answer (score 3):

A possible java 8 solution is the following:

```
    int[] skuNum = new int[num];
    int[] letters = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int[] l_p_Num = new int[] {11, 12, 13, 14};


    IntStream joined = IntStream.concat(IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(skuNum), IntStream.of(letters)), IntStream.of(l_p_Num));

    System.out.println(joined
            .boxed()
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a new `int[]` array to hold all the numbers and then use [`System.arraycopy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int)) to copy the smaller arrays into the `result` array:

```
int[] skuNum = new int[num]; // 1, 2
int[] letters = new int[4];  // 4, 5, 6, 7
int[] l_p_Num = new int[4];  // 9, 8, 7, 6

int[] result = new int[num + 8];
System.arraycopy(skuNum, 0, result, 0, num);
System.arraycopy(letters, 0, result, num, 4);
System.arraycopy(l_p_Num, 0, result, num + 4, 4);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

will output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 7, 6]
```

Comment: All that'll give is 0's

Answer (score 0):

So this is without the Java generics, just with for loops

```
int[] skuNum = {1,2,3};
    int[] letters = {4,5,6};
    int[] l_p_Num = {7,8,9};

    int[] finalInt = new int[skuNum.length+letters.length+l_p_Num.length];

    for (int i = 0; i<skuNum.length;i++) {
        finalInt[i] =skuNum[i];

    }

    for (int i = 0; i<letters.length;i++) {
        finalInt[i+skuNum.length] =letters[i];

    }
    for (int i = 0; i<l_p_Num.length;i++) {
        finalInt[i+skuNum.length+letters.length] =l_p_Num[i];

    }
    for (int i : finalInt)
        System.out.print(i);
```

Result:

```
123456789
```

If you want to have strings in it see this code:

```
        int[] skuNum = {1,2,3};
    String[] letters = {"asd","asd","aefuh"};
    int[] l_p_Num = {7,8,9};

    String[] finalArray = new String[skuNum.length+letters.length+l_p_Num.length];

    for (int i = 0; i<skuNum.length;i++) {
        finalArray[i] =String.valueOf(skuNum[i]);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i<letters.length;i++) {
        finalArray[i+skuNum.length] =letters[i];

    }
    for (int i = 0; i<l_p_Num.length;i++) {
        finalArray[i+skuNum.length+letters.length] = String.valueOf(l_p_Num[i]);

    }
    for (String st : finalArray)
        System.out.print(st);
```